# recognizing javascript, then doing an "include"

Tags: javascript, php, load, external

i need to do what would be a PHP include in a javascript file, but i don't even know if it's JQuery, or AJAX, or just plain old javascript. (i've found JQUery  and AJAX "load" functions, but they don't work in this script, operator error or whatever...)

in any case, I'm hoping someone could kindly recognize the javascript here and then tell me how I can load an external PHP in the third codeblock below..., please?

```
var simplemaps_usmap_mapdata = {

main_settings:{
    //General settings
    width: 'responsive', //or 'responsive'
    background_color: '#FFFFFF',    
    background_transparent: 'no',
    border_color: '#ffffff',
    popups: 'detect', //on_click, on_hover, or detect

    //State defaults
    state_description:   'State description',
    state_color: '#88A4BC',
    state_hover_color: '#3B729F',
    state_url: '#',
    border_size: 1.5,       
    all_states_inactive: 'no',
    all_states_zoomable: 'no' 
    etc...
```

and (minified):

```
(function(m){var F=function(a){var a=a.split("."),c=m,b;for(b=0;b<a.length;b++)c[a[b]]=c=c[a[b]]||{};return c},n=F("com.greensock"),o,k,d,z,G,v={},C=function(a,c,b,j){this.sc=v[a]?v[a].sc:[];v[a]=this;this.gsClass=null;this.def=b;var e=c||[],d=[];this.check=function(c){for(var f=e.length,g=0,l;-1<--f;)(l=v[e[f]]||new C(e[f])).gsClass?d[f]=l.gsClass:(g++,c&&l.sc.push(this));if(0===g&&b){var c=("com.greensock."+a).split("."),f=c.pop(),k=F(c.join("."))[f]=this.gsClass=b.apply(b,d);j&&((m.GreenSockGlobals|| m)[f]=k,"function"===typeof define&&define.amd?define((m.GreenSockAMDPath?m.GreenSockAMDPath+"/":"")+a.split(".").join("/"),[],function(){return k}):"undefined"!==typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=k));for(f=0;f<this.sc.length;f++)this.sc[f].check(!1)}};
ETC...
```

where i would like to load an external file would be in this TOOLTIP 'description' where i've placed an iframe - (if i'm loading 50 of these, wouldn't it me more code efficient to do an include vs an iframe?):

```
state_specific:{
    "GA": {
        name: 'Georgia',
        description: '<iframe src="../html5USmap/ga.php" style="width:200px; height:45px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" align="center" seamless></iframe>',
        color: 'default',
        hover_color: 'default',
        url: 'default'          
        },
```

I'm very grateful for anyone's assistance. I LOVE Stack Overflow - it's where I always end up when i'm googling for help... :)

thanks
Glenn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the value of `state_specific.GA.description` to be the markup that's generated by your PHP script at `../html5USmap/ga.php`?

In your PHP page or template, you want something like this:

```
<div id="map_description" style="display:none;">
    <?php include '../html5USmap/ga.php'; ?>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.mapDescriptionHtml = document.getElementById("map_description").innerHTML;
</script>
```

Then, change your `state_specific` javascript block to something like this:

```
"GA": {
    name: 'Georgia',
    description: window.mapDescriptionHtml,
    color: 'default',
    hover_color: 'default',
    url: 'default'          
},
```

You might want to refactor this to get the script out of your markup, and make sure everything runs in the right order, etc.

Comment: it says here not to use comments for thanks, but i want to thank you, so thank you. it looks neat, i'll give it a shot and reply back...

Because this is being done in Wordpress, which doesn't allow raw php on its own, i'm having to use a js/php plugin ... this is the extra little hurdle in making this happen. I'll let you know...